# How do I find and mount my windows drive in ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, window

I went to the home folder and looked under devices but there is no windows drive.

Comment: Any output of `lsblk`?

Answer (score 0):

Using the command `fdisk -l` will list all the devices and partitions on your PC. You can see which partitions are already mounted by using the `df` command and rule them out. Out of the remaining partitions in the output of `fdisk -l` the ones with SYSTEM HPFS/NTFS are the likely targets. If you have more than one Windows partition you can guess which is which by the size or just mount them in different locations and try.

Normally your windows partitions should at least be visible in your File Manager. Make sure you have ntfs-3g installed or install it using `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g` first before trying to mount the drives.

You can mount a drive to any existing empty directory using (replace the X in /dev/sdX with your partition number):

```
mkdir /mnt/windows-drive
mount -t ntfs-3g -o rw /dev/sdX /mnt/windows-drive
```